# can data-import-handler use HikariCP?

Tags: solr, hikaricp, data-import

I'm using solr4.5.1 in work.

The trouble is that a lot of `getConnection` occurred, when I execute data-import(full-import). So I thought if HikariCP could be used in data-import, but I haven't found  similar problem.

Is it possible? If so please advice.

**Solr 4.5.1** with Tomcat

**data-config.xml**

```
<dataSource driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" 
            name="jdbc" 
            url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@address/mydb" 
            user="user" password="pass"/>
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing your dataimport configuration? There may be better options than using a connection pool to avoid the excessive use of connections. The most prominent is [Entity Caching](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/uploading-structured-data-store-data-with-the-data-import-handler.html#entity-caching).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heavily borrowed from *David H Nebinger*'s post: [Tomcat and HikariCP](https://liferay.dev/blogs/-/blogs/tomcat-hikaricp).

**Install HikariCP**

To make use of JNDI, you need to declare the JNDI datasource with all its' settings, password and cache options within the JNDI declaration. This has nothing to do with Solr at this point. This is a Tomcat mechanism. How you do this is described in [this tutorial that also makes use of HikariCP](https://liferay.dev/blogs/-/blogs/tomcat-hikaricp).

First is to download the .zip or .tar.gz file from http://brettwooldridge.github.io/HikariCP/.  This is actually a source release that you'll need to build yourself.

Second option is to download the built jar from a source like Maven Central, https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.zaxxer/HikariCP

Once you have the jar, copy to the Tomcat `lib/ext` directory.  Note that Hikari CP does have a dependency on SLF4J, so you'll need to put that jar into `lib/ext` too.

Do not forget to place your datasource's JDBC driver in the `lib/ext` folder.

**Configure the JNDI datasource**

Location of your JNDI datasource `<Resource />` definitions depends upon the scope for the connections. You can define them globally by specifying them in Tomcat's `conf/server.xml` and `conf/context.xml`, or you can scope them to individual applications by defining them in `conf/Catalina/localhost/WebAppContext.xml` (where `WebAppContext` is the web application context for the app, basically the directory name from Tomcat's webapps directory).

Create the file `conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml` if it doesn't already exist. Use the table from https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#popular-datasource-class-names to find your data source class name, we'll need it when we define the  element.

```xml
<Resource name="jdbc/SolrPool" auth="Container"
    factory="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariJNDIFactory"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    minimumIdle="5" 
    maximumPoolSize="10"
    connectionTimeout="300000"
    dataSourceClassName="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"
    dataSource.url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@address/mydb"
    dataSource.implicitCachingEnabled="true" 
    dataSource.user="user" 
    dataSource.password="pass" />
```

**Make use of the JNDI datasource in Solr**

After you have followed this tutorial, you will need to use the declared JNDI datasource, this would be like [described in the Solr Wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandlerFaq#How_do_I_use_a_JNDI_DataSource.3F):

```xml
<dataSource
    jndiName="java:jdbc/SolrPool"
    type="JdbcDataSource"
    user="" password=""/> <!-- leave out user/password here -->
```

Comment: Mr. cheffe, thank you for your reply. And sorry for late.   I understood Solr with Tomcat can use HikariCP.  You say I should do like this?   <dataSource jndiName="jdbc/mydb" type= "javax.sql.DataSource" user="user" password="pass"/> (in data-config)   and define JNDI in context.xml of Tomcat.

Comment: No need to call me Mr ;) I have updated the answer, hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your polite answer!  I'll try it to follow your description.